# Dirichlet sufficient conditions satisfiability checking

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier-transform, dft

I have 4 signal functions like this:
$1.\ e^{-2t}u(t)$
$2.\ e^{-2|t|}$
$3.\ (1-\frac{|t|}{2014})(u(t+2014)-u(t-2014))$
$4.\ u(t)$
I know the answer would be the third option since the other ones have their Fourier transforms as in the table [here](https://ethz.ch/content/dam/ethz/special-interest/baug/ibk/structural-mechanics-dam/education/identmeth/fourier.pdf). However, I don't know how to use Dirichlet conditions to test their Fourier transform's existences. Can anybody show me the procedure to test those signals. thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say that only 4 does not satisfy the [Dirchlet conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_conditions).

1. Has only one discontinuity, is absolutely integrable $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-2t}u(t) dt = 1/2$.
2. Is just the function of item 1 made symmetric. No discontinuity and is absolutely integrable.
3. The term $(1 - |t|/2014)$ is not absolutely integrable, but since it is multiplied by $u(t + 2014) - u(t - 2014)$, the function is absolutely integrable.
4. Only one discontinuity, total variation of 1, but it is not absolutely integrable. $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} u(t) dt = \infty$.